# Ant hangs randomly with executing

Tags: java, ant, clearcase

I have noticed in recent times that when invoking my ant scripts to build and unit test my Java app, it randomly hangs at various points in the execution.

The ant scripts are been invoked from my local machine on my remote clearcase view.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Please advise if you can.

Answer (score 0):

"random" means you won't get an answer here.  Even if someone else does, the randomness suggests that the cause probably isn't the same as in your case.

Are you sure that maybe your unit tests aren't just running long from time to time?

Maybe you can attach VisualVM to your PID when running Ant to see what's going on with memory, or perhaps a profiler to pin it down.

But you're just guessing without data right now.

Comment: I've resorted to the use of 'random' as there is no set sub section of the ant build script where it starts hanging. Just wondering if anyone else has ever seen this issue. 

The ant build is scheduled to run overnight and last night, I found it had hung during the compliation before the JUnits even run.

I do believe that the issue is partly due to running the ant scripts on a remote clearcase view and maybe a dodgy connection is causing ant to hung without throwing a meaningful error.

Answer (score 0):

> remote clearcase view

That should mean **dynamic view** defined on a remote computer, meaning you have two level of network indirection:

- albd (atria location broker) remote calls from your local ClearCase instance to the view_server.exe on the remote computer
- RPC calls to the vobrpc_server from the remote computer to the central VOB server.

If your ant script depends on large binary files (jar for thridparty library), and if one of the two remote path has some issue, you can expect some lagging problem.

One solution is to have a local *snapshot* view referencing the large jars, and still using your remote dynamic view for building the sources.

Our experience is to only use snapshot view for regular building purposes, while dynamic views are enough for coding (with occasional builds).